# Listar archivos modis por dia

Tags: r

Necesito realizar una fusión de imágenes raster con los satélites de terra y aqua de modis en R. Para realizar el ciclo debo tener la misma longitud de los vectores de los satélites, sin embargo para terra tengo 6031 imágenes y para aqua 5277. No se como crear una data.frame solo con las imágenes en común que comparten el día, y dejar afuera a las que son únicas (sin pareja).

```
library(raster)
library(MODIS)

setwd("C:/Composite")

#Directorio Terra
mypath1<-"C:/Reclass_MOD"
myras1<-list.files(path=mypath1,pattern = glob2rx("*.tif$"), ## nc es la extension de HDF
                    full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)
name<-substr(myras8,16,31)

files1 <- stack(myras1)
date1<-extractDate(files1,asDate=TRUE,pos1=10,pos2=16,format= "%Y%j")

#Directorio Aqua
mypath2<-"C:/Reclass_MYD"
myras2<-list.files(path=mypath2,pattern = glob2rx("*.tif$"), ## nc es la extension de HDF
                    full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)
name1<-substr(myras2,16,31)

files2 <- stack(myras2)
date2<-extractDate(files2,asDate=TRUE,pos1=10,pos2=16,format= "%Y%j")

> data.frame(date1$inputLayerDates,date2$inputLayerDates)
Error in data.frame(date1$inputLayerDates, date2$inputLayerDates) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 6031, 5277
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar la función `%in%` para encontrar las fechas en común entre date1 y date2.

```
comun <- date1$inputLayerDates %in% date2$inputLayerDates
```

Entonces puedes usar comun para crear una nueva data frame.

```
data.frame(date1[comun, "inputLayerDates"], date2[comun, "inputLayerDates"])
```

En general, es más fácil usar la función `merge` para combinar data frames.

```
merge(date1, date2, by = "columna(s) en común")
```

Pero el código que proporcionas no permite conocer cuál es la estructura de tus datos.